# How to automatically mount a usb exFat sdcard?

Tags: pi-3

In order to do it with fstab I need the UUID.
But the uuid does not show up with this command:
 `root@raspberrypi 3 :/dev/disk/by-uuid# sudo blkid -o list -w /dev/null`

```
    device      fs_type     label     mount point           UUID

/dev/mmcblk0p1    vfat     RECOVERY  (not mounted)         C4AA-0C58
/dev/mmcblk0p5    ext4     SETTINGS  /media/pi/SETTINGS    25af7060-119f-4d9f-91cf-d1da0fad07b0
/dev/mmcblk0p6    vfat     boot      /boot                 D9F7-BBC2
/dev/mmcblk0p7    ext4     root      /                     136d6c40-08c4-4f3a-9044-41e33e5c233d`
/dev/sda1         exfat              /media/usb
```

I can mount and write on it when i use:
`mount -t exfat -o utf8,uid=pi,gid=pi,noatime /dev/sda1 /media/usb`